# What actually are physical registers and reorder Buffer?

Tags: memory, buffer, cpu-registers

During register renaming, reorder buffer and physical registers are usded. I don't understand what they're and where they're. are they sored in memory, or are  some unit on the cpu, or maybe are them just some virtual thing?

Answer (score 0):

Reorder buffer lives on the cpu chip. Physical registers on the chip too. They can't be in main memory as that will make them slow.

CSE P548 [Course material slides](http://www.slideshare.net/aaassshhh100/reorder-buf) contain a scheme explaining that.
[image: From the slides]

If you have more time to dedicate to this see the full course or e.g. [Pentium Pro and Pentium II System Architecture book](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=MLJClvCYh34C&pg=PA199&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=reorder%20buffer&f=false).

[image: ReOrder Buffer]